# Set view to orthographic

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How to take current view and set the view to orthographic?

I tried using viewer.getCamera() to get parameters how the view is currently set and then setting it with viewer.applyCamera().

```
var camera = viewer.getCamera();
console.log('Camera: ' + JSON.stringify(camera));
```

Which returns:

```
Camera: {
   "metadata": {"version":4.3,"type":"Object","generator":"ObjectExporter"},
   "object":{"uuid":"78D2EA86-853B-473F-9E0E-E3F0C8874E40",
   "type":"Camera",
   "matrix":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0.00009999999747378752,0,0,-0.00009999999747378752,1,0,114010.796875,88329.0078125,135503.609375,1],
   "children":[
       {"uuid":"53C7FA49-B00C-4616-9E7A-CCB94A661A45",
        "type":"DirectionalLight",
        "color":8355711,"intensity":0,
        "matrix":1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-0.5,0.20000000298023224,0.05999999865889549,1]},
        {
           "uuid":"7D5EC244-7268-4190-8480-4BD1DD56F8CB",
           "type":"Object3D","matrix":[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
        }]}}
```

Then I tried setting, with the "matrix" array as params, but the view jumps.

```
viewer.setViewFromArray(params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the format of an array with the data from current camera and applied them by viewer.setViewFromArray. I kept all other parameters, but only set the last param to 1 (ortho).It looks working well at my side.

```
 viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.setViewFromArray([
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().position.x,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().position.y,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().position.z,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().target.x,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().target.y,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().target.z,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().up.x,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().up.y,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().up.z,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().aspect,
    viewerApp.myCurrentViewer.getCamera().fov,
    1,
    1
]);
```

you can also check the source Viewer3D.js to get the workflow how setViewFromArray works.

*Viewer3D.prototype.setViewFromArray = function(params, name){....}*

IF you simply want to switch the view between perspective and orthographic, you can use the direct API:

Viewer.navigation.toOrthographic()

Viewer.navigation.toPerspective()

Comment: Hi Xiaodong,
just wondering why Viewer.navigation.toOrthographic() makes the camera to zoom into object (and reading the code, it actually moves the camera position)?